Forward and reply icon sometimes not showing up using Outlook 365 email
I use Office 365 for email and sometimes (not always but very often) when I forward or reply to an email, the small arrow icon that shows I have forwarded or replied does not show up next to the original email. Any help will be appreciated.

Clear cache: Try clearing your Outlook cache, which can resolve various display issues:
Close Outlook
Search for "%localappdata%" in the Windows start menu and open the folder
Navigate to Microsoft > Outlook
Delete the .ost file (your emails will resync from the server)
Restart Outlook

Which version of Outlook desktop client are you using?
Here are a few ways I recommend you to fix it:
Update your desktop client to the latest version.
Enter Windows+R first, then type outlook.exe /cleanviews (Leave a space after Outlook.exe)-> Click OK.
Enter Windows+R first, then type Outlook.exe /resetnavpane (Leave a space after Outlook.exe) -> Click OK.
(Note: There is a space between Outlook and ‘/’. The above mentioned command restores Outlook to default view settings and all the custom views that you created will be lost.)
If the above doesn't help, try to repair Office. Reference article:Repair an Office application.
